# Filtering NO and Yes in this pandaframe gives me empty result but i can manually view the YES AND NOs

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

I have this  https://pastebin.com/BYUdR7PW  sample.xlsx  and i want to  filter the YES and NO`s  and save them in  a file  differently  where  there is a file containing  the yes and  a separate one with  no with the respective Column Values (Headers and the  column with the yes /  no ) .
I am new to pandas  and  the code i was using is

```
labels = 'sample.xlsx'    
df  = pd.read_excel(labels)
df  = pd.read_excel(labels)
# df2 = df2.set_index('Notes_PRODUCER NAME:').to_dict()
# df =df2.T
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\s+', '_')  # in case there are multiple white spaces
df = df.set_index('Notes_PRODUCER_NAME:')
df = df.where(df.isin(['yes','no'])).stack().reset_index(name='val')
# #get for each User unique columns names
df = df.groupby('Notes_PRODUCER_NAME:')['level_1'].unique().reset_index(name='un_val')
df
```

How can  i do this  cause  my  code is not  working as  i want

The  result  i want  to resemble  this

```
 Notes_PRODUCER NAME:    |          FV 5.2   Sanitary Facilities_Compliance  


Swahn                    |
                         |             yes  
                         |             yes 
                                       yes 

Swahn                    |          Notes_DOES THE PRODUCER MAKE USE OF A CONSULTANT?

                                     NO
                 |

                 |

Sarah                    |              Notes_IS THE PRODUCER REGISTERED FOR PARALLEL PRODUCTION?

                                      NO
```

Comment: Without easy-to-access sample data it's hard to replicate, but `df.where(df.str.match('yes') | df.str.match('no'))` might work better.

Comment: there is  sample  data  at this  url  https://pastebin.com/Q6fiqwmT

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to help you if you provide a small amount of sample data in the question *or* if you clean up the pastebin data so it's just a small subset.

Comment: i have  added a small  subset  with  only  one row https://pastebin.com/BYUdR7PW